What are the complete steps to remove protected applications from macOS 14.4?
What are the complete steps for removing a protected application, for example Apple's TV.app from a fresh install of macOS 14.4 Sonoma?
What I tried:
In recovery mode, I ran this:
csrutil disable
csrutil authenticated-root disable

and rebooted.
This is not enough to delete TV.app:
sudo rm -rf /System/Applications/TV.app

It gives an errors about a Read-only file system.
This answer for macOS Catalina of:
sudo mount -uw /

Fails with the error:
mount: / failed with 66

These steps for Big Sur fail at the last step:
sudo bless --folder MOUNT_PATH/System/Library/CoreServices --bootefi --create-snapshot

Which gives the error:
bless: For Apple Silicon Macs, the 'folder' option is only supported for external devices.

Does anyone know what to do next?
I haven't found the complete steps online (yet). This may be more of a search-engine failure, however.

This particular issue is partly addressed on this Stack Overflow answer, but the final command needs to be changed slightly for Apple Silicon Macs on more recent versions of MacOS. The final command from this answer for macOS 12 works on macOS 14.4:
sudo bless --mount "$HOME/mount/System/Library/CoreServices/" --setBoot --create-snapshot

Note: Apple will undo your changes if you re-enable SIP, SSV, or update the operating system. There is no (known) way to stop them. (Although I might conjecture that running an opencore patched build might eventually support something of this sort).

This might generate more upvotes with just a factual answer & less opinion.

@Tetsujin thank you, done.

(From my own blind point of view, that which you called opinion seemed as fact; Apple's removal of user control over their own devices is a matter of fact, as is the fact that their motivation stems from their own corporate interests, sometimes with contempt for the rights, needs, and interests of the user. This is not opinion, nor especially controversial or novel–although I conceed it is distracting. It is important to understand that there is a firm reason why a better technical solution is inaccessible, and it is active efforts of corporate greed, not computational infeasability)

No, you started with fact 'Apple's boot volume is signed & sealed' then you added opinion as to why you think they did this. Moving that opinion to comments doesn't help your cause. Opinion is what Reddit thrives on. Here we prefer fact, with citations if possible.
